# Map pins clustering on WinRT MapControl

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing a WinRT application and I use the (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.) MapControl to display a map on the main page of my application. Then I add some XAML controls on it (with `mapControl.Children.Add(object)` in the form of pins).

My question is, is there any up-to-date and tested way to cluster those pins when my map gets zoomed out or if there are too many pins too close?

I have found the following: [Clustering Pushpins in Windows Store Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bingdevcenter/2013/10/15/clustering-pushpins-in-windows-store-apps/) but this is for Store Apps and not for WinRT apps...